# Cant get sftp to work with var/www folder

Tags: centos, sftp

so I setup sftp and it all worked fine. but the user dir is /usr/ftp_user and instead I would like the dir to be /var/www and restrict it only to the files in that folder.

My sshd_config

```
Match Group ftpaccess
ChrootDirectory %h
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

user ftp_user is added to the ftpaccess group.
I changed the home directory for the user to /var/www/ like:

```
usermod -d /var/www/ ftp_user
```

And the file permissions:

```
drwxr-x---. root root www
    drwxr-xr-x. ftp_user ftpaccess cronjobs
```

When I try to  connect with filezilla

```
Status: connecting to 149.210.194.176...
Status: Connected to 149.210.194.176
Status: Listing directory /
error:  Unable to open .: permission denied
```

Anyone knows what im doing wrong?

Comment: I tried `setenforce 0`but that doenst work

Comment: permissions on /var/www should be 755  (rwxr-xr-x) to allow ftp_user enter the directory.

Comment: @tonioc mate ur a legend!!